# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function when Backbone view is called inside another View

Tags: backbone.js

I have this backbone view ,when this page is rendered  a small content from child page will also rendered to parent page.

**parent page**

```
define([ 
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!../../../../school-admin/studentHealthRecord.html',
    'views/schoolModule/viewStudentHealthView'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Backbone,
    healthRecordTemplate,
    ViewStudentHealthView
) {

    var StudentHealthRecordView = Backbone.View.extend({
        // target item.
        el : $("#schoolContentOuterPnl"),

        render : function() {
            var data = {};
            // template
            var healthcompiledTemplate =  _.template(healthRecordTemplate, data);
            // append the item to the view's target
            this.$el.html(healthcompiledTemplate);
            this.viewHealthClickEvent();
        },

        // Event Handlers
        events : {
        },

        viewHealthClickEvent : function(){
            new ViewStudentHealthView({
                el : $("#divSchoolHealthViewEdit")
            });
        },
    });

    return new StudentHealthRecordView;

});
```

**child page**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!../../../../school-admin/viewHealthRecord.html'
], function(
    $,
    _,
    Backbone,
    ViewStudentHealthTemplate
) {

    var ViewStudentHealthView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },

        render : function() {
            // template
            var data = {};
            var ViewStudentHealthCompiledTemplate = _.template(ViewStudentHealthTemplate, data);
            // append the item to the view's target

            this.$el.html(ViewStudentHealthCompiledTemplate);
        },
        // Event Handlers
        events : {      
        }

    });

    return new ViewStudentHealthView;
});
```

When the parent page initialized , the child should be initialized too,But it is showing $ is not a function.

Comment: A `]` has been missed in dependencies list in the `define` of the `parent page`, is that a typo ?

Comment: it was a mistake ,actually ] is there i forgot to add.

Comment: btw, why do you return the `instance` of the view rather than `view` itself - in the `return` line of both views ? A module should return the `view` reference itself, not the class.

Comment: I am not sure if this is still an open question, here is a jsfiddle that displays correctly the views http://jsfiddle.net/gvazq82/ucsh066f/2/, as @Cyclone  mentioned you are wrongly returning an instance of the view instead of just the reference, like `return ViewStudentHealthView;`, if this question was solved, please mark as solved.

Comment: yah i removed the new keyword.but it is still showing $ is not function on
new ViewHealthRecordView({
        el :  this.$("#schoolContentOuterPnl")
       });